# Splitting strings from a series of user inputs

Tags: java, split

I am working on a problem that involves reading user string input until the user input is empty, upon which the white-spaces are split and printed. So far I can manage to split the whitespaces but when muliple user inputs are given it only splits and prints the first line. Please see image of my code so far below to get a better idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineByLine {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        if (input.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
        if (input.contains(" ")) {
            String[] tokens = input.split(" ");

            // Then print them 
            for (String token : tokens) {
                System.out.println(token);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't post your code on this site as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image.  For more on this, please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/522444). Also please check out the [ask] for more on-site best-practices.

Comment: I'd suggest reading the documentation on BufferedReader and use that rather than Scanner.

Comment: String words[] = reader.readLine().split(); The array will contain a list of the words in the line.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, my apologies I will not post images in future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the way you organized your code.  You call `readLine()` and then later you call `readLine()` within the `if/else`, then you print out the previous tokens and then call `readLine()` again without processing the previous one.

```
public class LineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            // check for empty line immediately.
            if (input.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
            // otherwise split it (and use the regular expression for one
            // more white spaces).
            String[] tokens = input.split("\\s+");

            // Add space for additional tokens.
            allTokens = Arrays.copyOf(allTokens, allTokens.length + tokens.length);
            // copy new tokens to array.
            int i = allTokens.length - tokens.length;
            for (String v : tokens) {
                allTokens[i++] = v;
            }
        }

        for (String token : allTokens) {
            System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
}
```

I changed your array from `whiteSpace` to `tokens` as you aren't really saving white space.

**Using an `ArrayList` instead of an array.**

Initialize it at the beginning.

```
List<String> allTokens = new ArrayList<>();
```

Append the items.

```
for (String str : tokens) {
   allTokens.add(str);
}
```

When done, print them.

```
for (String str : allTokens) {
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have realigned my code to the following with your help. But am still having an issue with the output. I need the for loop to execute and once complete - only then print the strings.I tried declaring a new String variable outside the for loop but am running into difficulty getting it to print the lines after the loop is complete. Please see original post for my updated code, thanks!

Comment: I modified my answer to show you how to increase the size of the array to append more items.  However, using an `ArrayList<String>` would make this easier because you simply allocate it once at the start and the just add values to it.  The appending code is transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Use `while (scanner.hasNext())` and remove the if/else condition. Then your code may work.

Comment: Unless you can signal an EOF (e.g. ctrl-D on *nix machines) `Scanner.hasNext()` may not work as required for console input as the scanner does not "know" when the user doesn't want to type in another line.  So it simply blocks and waits for user input.  This is unlike scanning in a `file` where the underlying filesystem signals an EOF when all data has been read.